# Flutter: How to get the main axis of the parent layout widget?

Tags: flutter

For example, how can I tell from a child widget if I'm in a parent widget with main axis of Axis.vertical like Column or a main axis of Axis.horizontal like a Row?

I contemplated of creating my own layout widgets with a provider for axis but believe there is a native way to find out the main axis of the parent widget.

Update: Found an article about creating a gap widget that checks the flex parent to figure out axis.

Comment: in what cases do you use it?

Comment: Trying to make a gap widget that takes  a size and then based on wether it’s in for instance a column or row figures out whether to extend the size as width or height.

Comment: idk your specific need, but if you want to try use `Wrap` widget. it has `spacing` for horizontal gap, and `runSpacing` for vertical gap.

Comment: Flex widget may be help you . Flex widget can get axis direction and by change this property can switch to column and row.

Comment: while it parent widget is telling the child , you can pass throw constructor